# Send different ajax calls at regular intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, intervals

I am working on visualising data through charts. I would like to send a different ajax call every X seconds. For example the first ajax call will be to say first.php and after x seconds the call will be to second.php. How can I bring in this notion through jQuery?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Better keep your file names to be called using AJAX in an Array

```
["first.php", "second.php", ..]
```

then do something like this using JavaScript `setTimeout`

```
`for(page in yourArray){
  (function fire() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html', 
    success: function(data) {
    //do your work with response
    },
   complete: function() {
   // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
   setTimeout(fire, yourXSeconds);
   }
  });
 })();
}`
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer as it is partially correct. But if I don't know the files to which the call goes beforehand what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me give an example to You:

- Let's say on the first.php you have:

  `<?php echo 'First Response'; ?>`

And on second.php

```
 `<?php echo 'Second Response'; ?>`
```

The output of the server-side script is passed as a parameter to the success handler function, so you'd have

`success: function(data) {
   alert(data); // First Response
}`

and

`success: function(data) {
   alert(data); // apple
}`

`<script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            alert('return sent');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "first.php",
                data: somedata;
                dataType:'text'; //or HTML, JSON, etc.
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
</script>`